# Find real $a$ for which $x^2 +|x-a|-3\lt 0$ is satisfied for negative $x$.

Tags: absolute-value

*Have problem solution given at: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/460988/424260, which am unable to understand. *

This problem's graphical soln. takes $|x-a|\lt 3-x^2$, & has right arm of the graph for $|x-a|$ first touching the curve for negative $a$, & then the left arm for positive $a$, with range between these two values of $a$ being asked for.

Am unable to get the stated values as given at the above link's answer :$$x^2+x-3\lt a\lt -x^2+x+3$$ has both l.h.s. ($x^2+x-3$) & r.h.s. ($-x^2+x+3$) having the roots given by same values  $x= \frac{-1\pm \sqrt{13}}{2}$.

So, the second para. is incomprehensible to me.

---

*Update* The approach chosen by the solution's analytical approach (also the one desired by me) is to not consider the two graphs separately, but to consider the points for which the modulus changes from $(x-a) \lt 0 $ to $\ge 0$. The range gives the value of $a$, & need take minima of the left side $(x^2+x-3)$ that represents the intersection of the right arm of the term $|x-a|$ with the parabola, as shown below:
$x-a\ge 0\implies x^2+x-3\lt a$

So, the minima represents the minimum positive value of $a$ that would yield the intersection of the right arm of $|x-a|$ with the parabola. This is minima as it is the smallest value of $x$ for the 'combined' curve, where any intersection is possible.

This minima can be found by taking derivative of the equality : $x^2+x-3=a$ wrt $x$, i.e. $\frac{\delta a}{\delta x} = 2x +1$, and taking second dervative to verify minima, get : $\frac{\delta^2 a}{\delta^2 x} = 2$; a positive value; hence minima. This minima is given at : $x = -\frac 12$. For this value of $x$, the value of $x^2 +x-3 = \frac14-\frac 12-3= -\frac {13}{4}$.

Next, need find maxima , as the left arm would intersect the curve; leading to 'cumulative' curve having a maximum value of $x$.

This maxima can be found by taking derivative of the equality : $-x^2+x+3=a$ wrt $x$, i.e. $\frac{\delta a}{\delta x} = -2x +1$, and taking second dervative to verify maxima, get : $\frac{\delta^2 a}{\delta^2 x} = -2$; a negative value; hence maxima. This maxima is given at : $x = \frac 12$. For this value of $x$, the value of $-x^2 +x-3 = -\frac14+\frac 12+3= \frac14 +3 = \frac{13}{4}$.

<del>Have two issues here:

(i) as the solution (at the given link) takes the same value of minima $x=-\frac12$ to get the maxima point for intersection of the left arm for positive value of $x$, by substituting in $-x^2+x+3$, i.e. $-\frac14-\frac12+3\implies -\frac34 +3\implies \frac94$.</del>

<del>(ii) the value obtained by me for maxima is invalid as it should be less than $\sqrt{3}$; but it is greater than that.

However, the values obtained by me for maxima ($\frac{13}4 = 3.25$) and minima (-$\frac{13}4 = -3.25$) values of $a$ in terms of $x$ are correct graphically, as shown at: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h0fuoqe7jc</del>

[image]

---

*Update 2* The link has given a very nice idea to just take the minima instead of finding roots of the concerned two quadratic equations;  <del>but it seemingly falters in finding maxima</del> & it uses the symmetric properties of both hyperbola & $|x-a|$ to unnecessarily find the intersection of left arm too at the same $x$ value.

The parabola is symmetrical around the y-axis,  hence it is logical that $a$ values (for maxima & minima) too are just a sign change only. Similarly, the function $|x-a|$ too is. In fact symmetric property is used by solution (at the link given) to derive the left arm 's value for $a$ for given $x=\frac12$.

  <del>In fact the value $a=\frac94$ is not apparent as to where it should belong to, as it gives two intersections of the left arm with parabola. Am very confused at its graphical interpretation.</del> 
 <del>The only possible interpretation is that the second intersection point is having coordinates  $x=-\frac12, y = \frac{11}4$, i.e. the chosen value of minima ($x=-\frac12$).</del> <del>So, it was a wrong idea for the solution (at given link) to put the minima value for left arm equation to find maxima.</del>

---

*Update 3* Need find not maxima, but the value of $a$ for which negative $x$ values are there. So, from minima $-\frac{13}4$ to $x\lt 3$ for which the left arm intersects parabola at y-axis. Will arrive at the value $a=3$ as below:
The $y$ coordinate is same for both parabola and the left arm intersection at y axis. It is a unique point. The value $-x^2+x+3= a$ gives the left arm equation. But, $x=0$, so $a=3$.
So, the value range for $a$ is from minima to less than $3$: $[-\frac{13}4, 3)$.

Comment: it is not $|x-a|\lt x^2-3$, but $|x-a|\lt 3-x^2$

Comment: I feel I deserve upvotes (many).

Comment: +1, I never down-voted your post, I just indicated the mismatch.

Comment: Request some analytical way, which is more succinct. Not happy with my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preparation:

- If we encounter an inequality $|x|<\beta$. If $\beta \le 0$, then no such $x$ exists. Otherwise, it is equivalent to $-\beta < x< \beta$.

Now, when we encounter the inequality $x^2+|x-a|-3<0$, this is equivalent to $$|x-a| < 3-x^2.$$

$$|a-x|< 3-x^2$$

Hence to have a solution, we need the condition that $3-x^2>0$, that is we are interested in the solution in $(-\sqrt3,0)$. Also, from the preparation material, we let $\beta=3-x^2$, and we have

$$-(3-x^2)<a-x < 3-x^2$$

which is just $$x^2+x-3<a<-x^2+x+3$$

[image]

Hence $a$ take values from  $(-\frac{13}4, 3).$

Remark: It is puzzling why you write $|x-a|<x^2-3$.

Edit $1$:

- The question of interest is find the value of $a$ when a negative $x$ exists that satisfies the inequality. Hence, we just have to look at negative part. In fact, we just have to look at $(-\sqrt3, 0)$. In fact, it is within this range that we have $x<0$ and also $x^2+x-3 < -x^2+x+3$ which is equivalent to $2(x^2-3)<0$.
- The curve $x^2+x-3=\left( x+\frac12\right)^2-3-\frac14=\left( x+\frac12\right)^2-\frac{13}4$ attains the minimal value at point $\left(-\frac12, -\frac{13}4 \right)$. Note that we have $-\sqrt{3} < -\frac12$.
- The curve $-x^2+x+3=-(x^2-x)+3=-\left(x-\frac12 \right)^2+3+\frac14$ which attains maximal value at point $\left(\frac12, \frac{13}4 \right)$. The maximal is attained at point $\left( \frac12, \frac{13}4\right)$. However, recall that we are interested in $-\sqrt{3}<x<0$, hence the supremum is $-0^2+0+3=3$.
- Hence $-\frac{13}4<a<3$
- [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oigcluxiev) is a desmos link, we can see when does $y=a$ lies in the region of interest.

Edit $2$:

The set of interest is \begin{align}A&=\{a: \exists x \in (-\sqrt{3}, 0), y_1(x) < a <y_2(x)\} \\
&=  \{a: \exists x \in (-\sqrt{3}, 0), y_1(x) < y <y_2(x), y=a\} \\\end{align}

Let $D=\{(x,y): -\sqrt{3}<x<0, y_1(x) < y<y_2(x) \}$, we are interested in knowing for which value of $a$ does the  $y=a$ intersect with $D$.

Also notice that $D$ doesn't include it's boundary. Hence $a\ne -\frac{13}4$.

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/l3hayyrpsv) is another desmos link that shaded the region in $D$. notice that $D$ doesn't include any boundary point. We can see that $A=(\inf_{(x,y) \in D}y, \sup_{(x,y)\in D}y)=\left( - \frac{13}4, 3 \right).$

Remark: The original solution in the previous posts is more rigorous. My approach uses a graph to help visualization.

Comment: Q.1. Seems like have forced the curve (parabola) on the negative x-axis. Cannot understand, as the parabola will be in both negative & positive x-axis, from  $x=-\sqrt{3}$, to $x=\sqrt{3}$.The curve that should shift is $|x-a|$ by shifting the value of $a$ from negative value of $x$ to positive $x$. The left intersection should give maxima for the right arm of $x-a$ with the parabola, & vice-versa. Q.2. I have doubt at the end of my Updated post regarding the different method chosen by answer (at link) for finding maxima. Please help. Q.3. Please tell why taken $|a-x|$ for the inverted curve.

Comment: Have corrected the mistake of taking $|x-a|\lt x^2-3$ in the edited post. Thanks a lot for pointing out that.

Comment: Request some analytical way, which is more succinct. Not happy with my approach.

Comment: Not able to understand how you got your solution range, am very interested to see the calculation.

Comment: The curve $y_1=x^2+x-3$ is for the right arm of $|x-a|$, while $y_2=-x^2+x+3$ is for the left arm; so it is the function value $y_1 <a<y_2$. The plotting of the two functions should be as at: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ivpxvnchl6, as the domain is negative values for $y_1$ & positive values for $y_2$. But, your approach of plotting these functions is graphically non-illuminating. And as $a$ is taken out, so do not know what combination of the two functions (parabola, left arm / right arm) is represented by them. Please help me see how to use it to graphically find solution.

Comment: Unclear abt. significance of fns. $y_1=x^2+x-3, y_2 =-x^2+x+3$ as $a$ is removed. What is meaning of such stripped out fns? Can they be called 'cumulative' fns. for 'right arm-parabola'; & 'left arm-parabola' respectively? Seems like parametric eqns. with parameter $a$ given by $2$ ranges by fns. $y_1, y_2$ for $y$ values, but $a$ should need $x$ coordinate values?-Q.2. $y=a\{max(\frac{-1-\sqrt{13+4a}}2, \cdots\}$ is unclear, & what is use of $x$. Not intuitive why ranges (for $x$) are taken as roots of $y_1,y_2$. Q.3. Your soln. seems different in terms of region chosen for soln. than others.

Comment: Why the minima point $a=-\frac{13}4$ is not included in the solution set? It should be the last intersection point of parabola and $|x-a|$ (right arm of it). At this point also $x$ is negative.

Comment: Waiting for your kindest response. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: responded in the edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But very difficult to acknowledge that $a$ is actually $y$-axis variable value. It means that the equation given has both $|x-a|$ (i.e. $|x-y|$) & the parabola clubbed. It is given & used all the way, but was not clear intuitively till now. 2. Also, very enlightening to know that the only reason was that $y_1\lt y\lt y_2$, for not including left boundary. 3. Still one question left : your solution region seems different than mine, or others.

Comment: there is more than one way to view a question. I thought mine is the same as coffeemath.

Comment: It means that you agree that based on your 'different' interpretation of problem have taken intersection in the negative x-axis of $y_1,y_2$ curves. This is different from my, or the solution (as per link), or the other answer's approach. I request is there an unambiguous treatment approach possible, to decide which one of the two is correct (or more correct). Also, what is coffeemath, I googled but of no avail.

Comment: Also, I feel that the solution (as per link) is following your approach of having the solution region in both 2nd & 3rd quadrant. But, the solution uses the minima to find intersection of left arm with parabola, & then takes the union to get the right end of the interval, i.e. $3$. This approach is not clear as per your last two graphs, where there is no intersection of the $y_1, y_2$ curves at minima, or anything that necessitates taking left arm's $a$ value at minima. I might be confused but you directly took two curves; while the solution took the intersection of left arm at minima, why?

Comment: My approach and the linked solution is very similar. His solution is more rigorous than mine. farruhota's approach is brilliant in the sense he uses the slope.

Comment: The solution (link) is using the right arm's $y_1$ to find minima. But your graph shows no minima in $y_1$ at $x=\frac12$. I am asking this to understand better the approach of solution that uses minima in the $y_1$ (right arm's intersection with parabola). Request a new graph to show that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78460/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jiten).

Comment: Have an idea to show in desmos, the two curves $y_1, y_2$ with actual $y=a$ coordinate value contributed by the two for any $x$ value. Have got curve with fn. # 11,13 mattering the most at : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tb6252ftm8, but am unable to show the difference. I mean, the function that shows the difference between $y_1 = x^2+x-3$ & $y_2=-x^2+x+3$ as $y_1-y_2$ should be a line (that you have referred to as 'strip') parallel to $y$-axis.

Comment: to create a line that is parallel to $y$-axis, perhaps going through $(a,0)$, try $x=a$, you can then set the upper and lower limit.

Comment: Unable to limit the vertical line by the last function #14 added at: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/feqtghtzsj. Once the valid domain is there, only a vertical line appears. Ideally, the value limit of $a$ should have given correct value for $x$, but fails! Out of any more idea.

Comment: change the $a$ in the constraint to $y$.

Comment: Yes, it worked (as at : https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ganp3aorvp); but am unable to fathom why putting $a$ did not work. Also, you told in chat that : " i look at things horizontally, he looks at things vertically."; so how to get horizontal strips. Would taking $y=a \{y_1\lt x\lt y_2\}$ work?

Answer (score 1):

> Determine all the values of the parameter $a$ for which the inequality $3−|x−a|>x^2$ is satisfied by at least one negative $x$.

Graphical method: at least one negative solution exists for $|x-a|\lt 3-x^2$ implies that the graph of absolute value function lies below the graph of quadratic function for $x<0 \ $ ($-\sqrt{3}<x<0 \ $ to be precise).

Refer to the graph below:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

The values of $a$ must range between $a_1$ and $a_2$ for the hand of absolute value function to stay below the parabola for $x<0 \ $ ($-\sqrt{3}<x<0 \ $ to be precise).

Since the slope of the hand is $1$, it is easy to find $a_2=3$ from $B(0,3)$.

The point $A$ is a tangent point to the parabola of a tangent line with slope $1$. Hence:
$$y'=(3-x^2)'=-2x=1 \Rightarrow x_0=-0.5 \Rightarrow y_0=3-(-0.5)^2=2.75.$$
The tangent line is:
$$y=2.75+1\cdot (x-(-0.5))=x+3.25,$$
whope $x$-intercept is $(-3.25,0)$, hence: $a_1=-3.25$.

At last, the solution is: $a\in (-3.25,3)$.

Comment: Really good, and was thinking on that terms, but could not materialize the idea to use slope of $45^0$.

Comment: thank you and good luck!

Comment: Please tell which s/w or online site is used to draw the displayed graph.  It has plotted for different values of $a$ the function $|x-a|$.

Comment: It is MS Excel. I deliberately chose the values $a=-3.25; -2;0;3$ to draw, then showed the min/max values must be $-3.25$ and $3$.